# What is ging wrong with my code! unable use show / hide

Tags: jquery, show-hide

```
    first way what i used
    if(b.model_serial_batchno ==='U')
    {
    $( '.medi_kit_tets' ).toggle( display );
    }

  second way   
    if(b.model_serial_batchno ==='U')
    {
    $('.medi_kit_tets').show();
    }
    else if(b.model_serial_batchno !='U')
    {
    $('.medi_kit_tets').hide();
    }
```

Even i tried using else also no luck.. And i will get many b.model_serial_batchno many  values like b.model_serial_batchno === 'B'/'D' etc..
is there any better way to solve this!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to specify "display" within the toggle. just use:

```
 if(b.model_serial_batchno ==='U')
    {
      $('.medi_kit_tets').toggle();
    }
```

and assuming that "b.model_serial_batchno" is EXACTLY equal to "U" and that you have an element with the "medi_kit_tets" class and that it is currently set to display:none - this will show it. Conversely if it is currently showing - this will hide it.

Comment: thanks for time.my div tag looks like <div class = "medi_kit_tets" style = "display:none">//some thing</div>.it was not working if b.model_serial_batchno !='U' it was not getting hide

Comment: happy to help. Good luck with your coding. Gav

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()`

```
if(b.model_serial_batchno ==='U')
{
   $('.medi_kit_tets').fadeIn();
}
else
{
    $('.medi_kit_tets').fadeOut();
}
```